# Syntax error near unexpected token 'newline' error while installing .deb packages offline

Tags: software-installation, 17.10

Whenever I try to install some `.deb` packages which I downloaded before (e.g. Atom, BP-tools etc.) I receive this error in Ubuntu 17.10:

```
./bp-tools_17.12_amd64_Xenial_free.deb 
./bp-tools_17.12_amd64_Xenial_free.deb: line 1: syntax error near
unexpected token `newline' ./bp-tools_17.12_amd64_Xenial_free.deb:
line 1: `!<arch>'
```

can anyone help, please?

Comment: are they really .deb files?; ie. if you `file bp-tools*.deb`  do they report something like "Debian binary package (format 2.0)"

Comment: You are trying to execute a .deb, .deb are not executable, you're expected to install them, for instance by using `dpkg -i package.deb`.

Answer (score 14):

Try installing the software with

```
dpkg --install <Package_Name>
```

Like in your case just `cd` into the directory and then type the above command like

```
dpkg --install libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 3):

to install `.deb` packages use full path. say you have a `.deb` package in `/home/yourname/Downloads/packagename.deb` then use:

```
sudo apt-get install /home/yourname/Downloads/packagename.deb
```